Questions about AWS Auto Scaling
I want to use AWS auto-scaling but I have a question about the files present in the Volume. I'll explain it better below:
1 - I want to scale my application made in PHP with MYSQL database.
2 - The Database must be unique using RDS so that new EC2 instances can save and use the same data without losing information.
3 - The question is about the new EC2 instances, whether they will have their own Volume or will have to be made a single scalable Volume like the RDS solution for MYSQL.
4 - Some information, such as profile image, is saved in the EC2 Volume, so my question is that when generating several EC2s via Auto-Scaling, this information will be lost or not found by my App?
Thanks

I think this should clear things up.

In an ASG, every server is a totally distinct/unrelated instance created from the AMI you selected when creating it (in the Launch Template or whatever).
You can customize your AMI to preinstall your app, add extra files, install tools, etc as needed.  Tools like Packer tend to be used for this.
You can further “set up” the servers as they start up by running commands in user data (kind of a script you define in the launch template that runs when the server is coming up) if needed.
Instances will have their own volumes.  You can use something like EFS (similar to NFS) to share data between instances as a secondary volume though.  Last I checked, I think an EBS volume can also be multi attached to 16 instances, but EFS is better for HA, etc anyway as it can be in multiple AZs.

